# Route [/math/{ $math->id }/question] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I was working on a project earlier on and ran into this error

*Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [/math/{ $math->id }/question] not defined.*

Here's my route:

```
Route::post('/math/{math}/question', [App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController::class, 'store'])->name('/math/{math}/question')->middleware('auth');
```

Blade File Route:

```
<form action="{{ route('/math/{ $math->id }/question') }}" method="post">
```

Controller:

```
public function create(Math $math)
{
    return view('question.create', compact('math'));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::post('/math/{math}/question', [App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController::class, 'store'])->name('mathQuestion')->middleware('auth');

<form action="{{ route('mathQuestion', ['math' => $math->id]) }}" method="post">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

- 1st, `route()` uses the `->name()` parameter.
- 2nd, `math/{math}/question` is not a good route name.

Change your name to something sensical, like `math_question,` then fix your code:

```php
Route::post('/math/{math}/question', [App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController::class, 'store'])->name('math_question')->middleware('auth');
```

Then:

```html
<form action="{{ route('math_question', ['math' => $math->id]) }}" method="post">
```